# Font only works in parts of LibreOffice

Tags: libreoffice, fonts

I am making charts in LibreOffice Calc -- I've been able to set the font on the axes and titles to Times New Roman, but when I try to change the font on a text box I have inserted in to the chart, it tells me "This font has not been installed. The closest available font will be used."

I've tried making sure the microsoft fonts are installed, ran the fc-cache command. Any ideas of what to try next?

Comment: Did you install Microsoft fonts?

Comment: yes, i verified they were installed

`tarab@Grey:~$ sudo apt-get install ttf-mscorefonts-installer
[sudo] password for tarab: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
ttf-mscorefonts-installer is already the newest version (3.6ubuntu2).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 29 not upgraded.`

Comment: When you select a text box and navigate to Format - Format Selection - Font - Western Text Font Family, is Times New Roman one of the selections in the drop-down menu?

Comment: TNR isnt on the dropdown menu, but im getting to the font selection a different way. Since it's a text box in the chart, when i select it format --format selection isnt available. I'm right clicking and selecting "character" which brings me to a dropdown menu where TNR isnt there